# Chef how to bootstrap many nodes each node having its own role?

Tags: bash, chef-infra, string-interpolation

Can someone help me understand how should i write this command:

```
knife bootstrap $vm1 -N $vm1 -x root -P $pass -r 'role[$role]'
```

The error i'm getting is:

```
ERROR: The data in your request was invalid
Response: Field 'run_list' is not a valid run list
```

In other words, how do I put a variable in my run list?

Thank you,
Gabriel

Comment: The single quotes around `role[$role]` are preventing shell interpolation of `$role`.  Try using double-quotes.

Comment: I did that. it worked. Thank you.